# Android : progrees bar like sea waves

Tags: user-interface, android

Am implementing a progress bar in Android which is similar to the Clean Master app.
 It looks like sea waves filling the space in accordance to the progress value.
Please suggest ideas on how to achieve this in native android development. 
[image]

Comment: can try https://github.com/john990/WaveView

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create create the animation using different bitmaps and then using an xml to create the animation, of course this requires good graphic skills but i think it is the easiest way to do it.